# How to Get Array From URL Encoded String?

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, urlvariables

I'm sure this is a very easy thing but I couldn't find it in google for hours.
I'm new to ActionScript and I'm trying to obtain an array of variables from a string that is generated by a .php file.

my php file outputs this:

```
var1=42&var2=6&var3=string
```

And my ActionScript code is:

```
public function CallAjax_VARIABLES(url:String , the_array:Array) 
{ 
 var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url); 
 var variables:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
 variables.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
 variables.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, VARIABLES_Complete_Handler(the_array)); 
 try 
 { 
  variables.load(request); 
 }  
 catch (error:Error) 
 { 
  trace("Unable to load URL: " + error); 
 } 
} 

function VARIABLES_Complete_Handler(the_array:Array):Function {
  return function(event:Event):void {
  var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target); 
  //the_array = loader.data;   // this doesn't work.  
  //the_array = URLVariables.decode(loader); // this doesn't work either.
  //trace(loader.data['var1']); // this outputs 42, so I'm getting the string from php.
  };
}
```

I think you already understood this but, in the end, I want to have an array (**In ActionScript**) that will give me:

```
the_array['var1']=42;
the_array['var2']=6;
the_array['var3']="string";
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?
Thanks!

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to get variables FROM php TO ActionScript.
e.g. My PHP file correctly converts the array to an html query, But I don't know how to parse them in an array in ActionScript.

Comment: Did my reply help you?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`URLVariables`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLVariables.html) for this.

```
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
```

This way you can simply say:

```
trace(vars.var2); // 6
```

An array would be useless here as the result is associative rather than index based, though you can easily take all the values and throw them into an array with a simple loop:

```
var array:Array = [];
for(var i:String in vars)
{
    array.push(vars[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I thought this was a PHP question. In ActionScript, try this:

```
 var the_array:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
 the_array.decode(loader.data);

 trace(the_array.var1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is in ActionScript side. I'm trying to parse variables from the string that is generated correctly by PHP.

Comment: Made an edit, try now. You where correct about URLVariables though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for parse_str function

```
parse_str($str, $output);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is in ActionScript side. I'm trying to parse variables from the string that is generated correctly by PHP.